# C# webbrowser как двигать скрол?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. В webbrowser открывается страничка, в ней есть скрол. Как можео им управлять? Подвинуть вверх, вниз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще способы:

```
WebBrowser.Document.Window.ScrollTo(int x, int y);
WebBrowser.Navigate("javascript:window.scroll(...);");
```

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток. Для управления скролом на веб странице вам надо смотреть в сторону Js (jQuery). Вот ряд статей которые могут вам помочь:

1. `[событие scroll][1]`
2. [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://xiper.net/collect/js-plugins/effects/scrollto)

статьи не самые новые, но дадут вам отправную точку). удачи